# Spring cloud server not accessing all profiles from Vault backend

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault

I am new to HashiCorp Vault and setting up spring cloud config server having Vault as a backend for storing secrets, keys, etc.

The problem is I am able to access the secrets that are stored at default level like :

```
curl -X "GET" "http://localhost:8888/myapp/default" -H "X-Config-Token: XXX"
```

However, I am unable to access the profile specific secrets that I stored in Vault. No matter which profile I store the secrets in, the API always returns default values and not profile specific values.

for e.g:

```
curl -X "GET" "http://localhost:8888/myapp/prod" -H "X-Config-Token: XXX"
```

Here are my secrets stored on dev instance of Vault(ver 1.1.3):

```
1. vault kv put secret/myapp foo=myappsdefault
2. vault kv put secret/myapp/prod foo=myappsprod
```

**Spring cloud config server application.yml:**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: vault
  cloud.config.server.vault.kvVersion: 2
server:
  port: 8888
```

**Spring cloud server pom.xml:**

```
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
                <relativePath/>
            </parent>

            <properties>
                <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

**Expected:**

```
curl -X "GET" "http://localhost:8888/myapp/prod" -H "X-Config-Token: XXX"

{
"name": "myapp",
"profiles": [
  "prod"
],
"label": null,
"version": null,
"state": null,
"propertySources": [
  {
"name": "vault:myapp",
"source": {
"foo": "myappsprod"
}
}
],
}
```

**Actual:**

```
{
"name": "myapp",
"profiles": [
  "prod"
],
"label": null,
"version": null,
"state": null,
"propertySources": [
  {
"name": "vault:myapp",
"source": {
"foo": "myappsdefault"
}
}
],
}
```

**Here are vault outputs:**

```
vault kv get secret/myapp/prod


=== Data ===
Key    Value
---    -----
foo    myappsprod


vault kv get secret/myapp

=== Data ===
Key    Value
---    -----
foo    myappsdefault
```

So the question becomes why is spring cloud server only querying default profile secrets and not environment specific?

Just as a side note, the profiles are getting applied to GIT files that I stored in repo, while integrating the spring cloud server with GIT as backend and I am expecting something similar with Vault.

Comment: I have referred the code from: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-config-vault

Answer (score 2):

After much struggling with configurations. I tried adding additional properties in my application.yml, and this helped in my case.

Snapshot of application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  profiles:
    active: vault
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          port: 8200
          host: 127.0.0.1
          kvVersion: 1
          backend: kv
          profileSeparator: /
          #skipSslValidation: true
          #defaultKey: signing

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```

The additonal things are:
1. I changed the backend from secret to kv(my custom secrets engine)
2. Profile separator as / (Use / in .yml)

In my case 'profileSeparator' key did the trick